# Unable to run Selenium headless in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, maven, headless

I want to use API to automate something but facing problem via headless browser. Everything is working fine without Spring Boot but with boot facing issue "org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities".

Below is the pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.boraji.tutorial.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-hello-world-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these dependencies :

```
<!-- SELENIUM DEPENDENCIES ( WORKING VERSION )-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I did the same but i think selenium 2.53.1 does not support headless mode. Facing issue in "FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions()".

Comment: You can use a different version which supports it. Just need to change the version.

Comment: i did but version other then  2.53.1 that again gave "org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities" error